# Entity Framework Core table filters (where a table has more than one use)

Tags: entity-framework, ef-core-2.2

I have inherited an SQL Server database where the original developer has used a single table to represent all "lookup" types rather than specifying a table for each...

```
create table Lookup (
    LookupID int,
    LookupType int,
    LookupKey int,
    LookupValue varchar(50)
)
```

The table is then used (for example) to provide different lists based upon the LookupType, so you would see data such as...

```
ID     Type     Key     Value
1      1        1       Mr
2      1        2       Mrs
3      1        3       Miss
4      2        1       Dog
5      2        2       Cat
6      2        3       Hamster
```

I need to use this table with Entity Framework Core as I want to be able to pull back the lookup values when querying data. Take the following table for example...

```
create table Customer (
    CustomerID int,
    CustomerTitleID int, <- LookupType = 1
    PetTypeID int -- LookupType = 2
)
```

And the data would look like...

```
ID     TitleID     PetTypeID
1      1           1
```

I can define a "Lookup" class...

```
public class Lookup {
    public int LookupID {get; set;}
    public int LookupTypeID {get; set;}
    public int LookupKey {get; set;}
    public string LookupValue {get; set;}
}
```

And I can define a "Customer" class...

```
public class Customer {
    public int CustomerID {get; set;}
    public Lookup CustomerTitle {get; set;}
    public int CustomerTitleID {get; set;}
    public Lookup PetType {get; set;}
    public int PetTypeID {get; set;}
}
```

The problem is that though (in DbContext.OnModelCreating) I can specify a "Principle Key" for the Customer/Lookup relationships...

```
entity<Customer>().HasOne<Lookup>(c => c.CustomerTitle).WithMany().WithForeignKey(c => c.CustomerTitleID).WithPrincipleKey(l => l.LookupKey);
entity<Customer>().HasOne<Lookup>(c => c.PetType).WithMany().WithForeignKey(c => c.PetTypeID).WithPrincipleKey(l => l.LookupKey);
```

I cannot find any way to set a filter for each "Lookup" class to limit it by "LookupTypeID".

I have tried creating a custom "PetType" class and associating it with the "Lookup" along with a filter (in DbContext.OnModelCreating)...

```
entity.HasQueryFilter(lookup => lookup.LookupType == 2);
```

however EF does not like more than one entity type being associated with a table unless the entity types are also related (the "PetType" would have to inherit from "Lookup").

I then inherited that custom "PetType" class from "Lookup" and tried the same filter...

```
entity.HasQueryFilter(petType=> petType.LookupType == 2);
```

but EF will only allow such a filter at the root level.

I have also tried using Views, however whilst a DbSet entity can be a child property of a DbQuery entity, it seems that it does not work the other way around.

Am I missing another way? The end result I am looking to be able to achieve is..

```
from customer in dbContext.Customers
    .Select new
    {
        customer.CustomerID,
        Title = customer.CustomerTitle.LookupValue,
        PetType = customer.PetType.LookupValue
    }
```

and have EF automatically apply a filter to each Lookup (obviously specified by me) so that the correct rows are selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually work around this "design" by creating an TPH inheritance hierarchy in EF Core.  eg:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;

namespace EfCoreTest
{

    public abstract class Lookup
    {
        public int LookupID { get; set; }
        public int LookupTypeID { get; set; }
        public int Key { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomerTitle : Lookup
    {

    }
    public class PetType : Lookup
    {

    }
    public class Customer
    {
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }
        public CustomerTitle CustomerTitle { get; set; }
        public int CustomerTitleID { get; set; }
        public PetType PetType { get; set; }
        public int PetTypeID { get; set; }
    }


    public class Db : DbContext
    {
        readonly string connectionString;

        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Lookup> Lookup { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CustomerTitle> CustomerTitles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PetType> PetTypes { get; set; }

        public Db(): this("server=.;database=EfCoreTest;Integrated Security=true")
        {

        }
        public Db(string connectionString)
        {
            this.connectionString = connectionString;
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Lookup>()
                .HasAlternateKey(e => new { e.LookupTypeID, e.Key });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Lookup>()
                .HasDiscriminator(e => e.LookupTypeID);

            modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerTitle>()
                .HasDiscriminator()
                .HasValue(1);
            modelBuilder.Entity<PetType>()
                .HasDiscriminator()
                .HasValue(2);

            var fks = from et in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
                      from fk in et.GetForeignKeys()
                      where typeof(Lookup).IsAssignableFrom(fk.PrincipalEntityType.ClrType)
                      select fk;
            foreach (var fk in fks)
            {
                fk.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict;
            }

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }



    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            using (var db = new Db())
            {
                db.Database.EnsureDeleted();
                db.Database.EnsureCreated();

                var Mr = new CustomerTitle() { Key = 1, Value = "Mr" };
                var Mrs = new CustomerTitle() { Key = 2, Value = "Mrs" };
                var Miss = new CustomerTitle() { Key = 3, Value = "Miss" };
                db.CustomerTitles.AddRange( new []{ Mr,Mrs,Miss});

                var Dog = new PetType() { Key = 1, Value = "Dog" };
                var Cat = new PetType() { Key = 2, Value = "Cat" };
                var Hamster = new PetType() { Key = 3, Value = "Hamster" };
                db.PetTypes.AddRange(new[] { Dog,Cat,Hamster });

                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            using (var db = new Db())
            {
                var titles = db.CustomerTitles.ToDictionary(t => t.Value);
                var petTypes = db.PetTypes.ToDictionary(t => t.Value);

                var cust = new Customer();
                cust.CustomerTitle = titles["Mr"];
                cust.PetType = petTypes["Hamster"];

                db.SaveChanges();
            }


            Console.WriteLine("Hit any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();


        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can create views for the lookups like:

```
create or alter view CustomerTitle
as
select [Key] CustomerTitleId, Value
from Lookup
where LookupTypeID = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get a System.InvalidOperationException: 'A discriminator property cannot be set for the entity type 'CustomerTitle' because it is not the root of an inheritance hierarchy.' (I am using EF Core 2.2.4 if that matters).

Comment: My bad; included the property name in the HasDiscriminator of the CustomerTitle class. Corrected that, but now I am getting the following: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot set discriminator value '2' for discriminator property 'Discriminator' because it is not assignable to property of type 'System.String'.'; even though the property is an int and the value I am setting is an int.

Comment: Try pasting that sample into an empty project and running it before integrating into your existing project.

Comment: Just completed that (figured it was my mistake); all works as you are expecting. Not sure I understand how EF knows to lookup "Key" instead of "LookupID" though - is this a convention based configuration and if so is there some documentation you can point me to? Still cannot get it working in my own project though - will get back to you as soon as I know why.

Comment: It's looking up LookupID, not Key.  eg Customer.CustomerTitleID -> Lookup.LookupID.

Comment: Customer would have to have both a CustomerTitleID and CustomerTitleLookupType to reference the Lookup.Key, assuming Lookup.Key is not an alternate key.

Comment: Ahh; that breaks it again then. The original problem (perhaps I was not clear on this) was that the design I have inherited uses the LookupKey as the value stored in the CustomerTitleID and PetTypeID columns, not the LookupID as would be expected. I had hoped I could overcome this with a combination of what you have done with the Discriminator above and my own playing with HasPrincipleKey but if I try and configure the model with Principle Keys I get an exception when initially populating the data...

Comment: I thought:             modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
                .HasOne<CustomerTitle>(e => e.CustomerTitle).WithMany().HasForeignKey(c => c.CustomerTitleID).HasPrincipalKey(ct => ct.Key);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
                .HasOne<PetType>(e => e.PetType).WithMany().HasForeignKey(c => c.PetTypeID).HasPrincipalKey(ct => ct.Key);

Comment: but System.InvalidOperationException: 'The instance of entity type 'PetType' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Key: 1}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.'

Comment: Yes.  Lookup.Key would have to be an AlternateKey for Lookup.  The _other_ workaround is to create a bunch of views for the different lookup types.  Or even to generate the seperate lookup tables from the main one.

Comment: I tried using views, but they cannot be a child property of an entity; an entity can be a child property of a view though! Lookup.Key cannot be an alternate key because it is not unique (unless I am missing something; this is where I thought principle keys would help).

Comment: That gives me the same error with duplicate key values when saving the PetType's; the LookupTypeID is not being set (for CustomerTitle and/or PetType) and is always zero.

Comment: You would never modify the lookups through the views.  Modify them through the main Lookup Table.  To enable modification on the views, you would need INSTEAD OF triggers.